# Pass multiple results from SQL query (by ButtonClick) to same TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, webforms

I'm trying to pass multiple results from (same) SQL query to one TextBox, however I'm receiving only one value (result). Why? TextBox has TextMode with Multiline.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\logi.accdb";

            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Action_time, User_name, Value_type, New_value FROM action_history"))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (OleDbDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        sdr.Read();
                        TextBox1.Text = sdr["Action_time"].ToString() + " " + sdr["User_name"].ToString()
                            + " " + sdr["Value_type"].ToString() + " " + sdr["New_value "].ToString();
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should iterate the data reader and inside the iteration concatenate the data in the `Text` property of the `TextBox`. Something similar to `while (sdr.Read()) { TextBox1.Text += "your data reader data"; }`

Comment: Should say to "_why I am receiving only one value?_" That the answer is quite simple, you are only shwing the first record fetched deom the database. Check the documentation of the [OleDbDataReader.Read()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) function. It says "_Advances the OleDbDataReader to the **next record**._"

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) regarding the `Read()` method of the OleDbDataReader. It returns a boolean value, if true than there are more rows to return. If not then it'll return false.

so instead of just using this `sdr.Read();` you should be using `while(sdr.Read())`. Using it like this will return all the results from the query you executed.

Also do not assign the results to the textbox like that, doing like so will overwrite the text of the textbox. Rather use a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0) for creating the text you want to assign to the textbox. After all the results are appended to the StringBuilder in the while loop, you can then assign it to `TextBox1.Text`.

```
// outside the while loop
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

while (sdr.Read())
{
// inside the while loop
    var result = sdr["Action_time"].ToString() + " " + sdr["User_name"].ToString()
                                + " " + sdr["Value_type"].ToString() + " " + sdr["New_value "].ToString();
    StringBuilder.AppendLine(result);

}
// outside the while loop
TextBox1.Text = stringBuilder.ToString()
```

Comment: This statement "_It returns a boolean value, if true than there are more rows to return_" is missleading, it could be confused with `HasRows` property. You should rephrase it to "_it returns true if it did fetch a row_". Also you could add the `while` statement to the code block so OP can see its usage.